# Python 2.x regex: halve all measures in px ("10px" becomes "5px" and so on)

Tags: python, regex

I've an xml file holding many measures in px such as "12px" "20px". I'd like to halve all these measures. That is, replace "12px" by "6px" and so on. Can this be done with a regex?

Odd numbers of pixels may be rounded upwards ("7px" becomes "4px") but that should happen naturally because all numbers are integers and I'm on Python 2.x.

*Finding* the measures isn't the hard part. For instance

```
myString = '''fontSize="12px" and marginLeft="19px" and paddingTop="10px"'''
print re.sub(r'\d+px','hello',myString)
```

But how do I pass the integer part from the matched re into the replacement (after dividing it by 2)? Any suggestions?

Comment: "but that should happen naturally because all numbers are integers and I'm on Python 2.x". Python 2 would mean 7 goes to 3. Float values are rounded down.

Comment: Right. Sorry, haven't written any Python for a long time.

Comment: No problem, just thought it was worth pointing out.

Answer (score 4):

Add a capturing group around `\d+` and use a lambda function as a replacement argument and perform the necessary operations on the Group 1 value:

```
import re
myString = '''fontSize="12px" and marginLeft="19px" and paddingTop="10px"'''
print(re.sub(r'(\d+)px', lambda m: "{}px".format(int(m.group(1)) / 2), myString))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KZdmsl)

**More details**:

- `(\d+)` - 1 or more digits (as `+` is a greedy quantifier matching 1 or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern, as many as possible)
- `px` - a literal char sequence

When a match object is passed to the lambda, it contains 2 groups: `.group(0)` (or `.group(0)`) holds the whole match (e.g. `10px`) and `.group(1)` contains the digits (e.g. `10`). To divide the number found, it should be converted to `int`, and the resulting replacement is build dynamically using `.format`.

Comment: That's awesome! Would you mind explaining your solution a bit more? Is the group 1 (rather than zero) indexed?!

Comment: I have added explanations. Is everything clear now? Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 2):

To round upwards you can use `math.ceil()` but you can also use bitwise operators (this way you don't have to import the math package):

```
import re
myString = '''fontSize="12px" and marginLeft="19px" and paddingTop="7px"'''
print(re.sub(r'[0-9]+(?=px)', lambda m: str((int(m.group()) + 1 >> 1)), myString))
```

or with the math package:

```
import re
import math
myString = '''fontSize="12px" and marginLeft="19px" and paddingTop="7px"'''
print(re.sub(r'[0-9]+(?=px)', lambda m: str(math.ceil(int(m.group())/2)), myString))
```